# Compile project for Microsoft detours 4.0.1 x64

Tags: c++

I am trying to migrate this project([Paybreak - Defense against cryptographic ransomware](https://github.com/BUseclab/paybreak)) to use latest [MS Detours 4.0.1.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/detours/) library which is for x86/x64 platforms. It compiles correctly with 32bit library but if compiling project for 64bit and using Detours 64bit then there is this error:

```
    antiransom.cpp(711) : error C2664: 'ReadProcessMemory' : cannot convert parameter 5 from 'DWORD *' to 'SIZE_T *'
Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
```

What causes this? I am able to compile other sample tool(kEncrypt) to x64 without issues.

Comment: Check if `DWORD` (usually `unsigned long`) and `SIZE_T` are actually the same type. If so, use `static_cast<SIZE_T *>(your_param)` to convert the parameter type.

Comment: DWORD bytesRead = 0; If changed to SIZE_T bytesRead=0 then it compiles without errors but for some reason when hook to 64-bit process halts the process to which it is attached.

Comment: Probably for 64-bit process `DWORD` and `SIZE_T` don't have the same size.